# Gaussian integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-(x+\mathrm iY)^2)\,\mathrm d x$ along $[-R,R]+\mathrm i[0,Y]$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, curves, gaussian-integral

> Use integration along $\partial Q$ of $Q=[-R,R]+\mathrm i[0,Y]$ to show that for all $Y\geq 0$ it holds that
>
> $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-(x+\mathrm iY)^2)~\mathrm dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-x^2)~\mathrm dx.$$

Similiar to one of my other questions referring to a rectangle I was going to rewrite $\partial Q$ as four curves but the integrands became really complicated. <strike>Using the bottom curve of the rectangle I got $\require{cancel}\cancel{\gamma(t)=(1-t)(-R)+tR=R(2t-1)}$ hence</strike>

$$\cancel{\int_\gamma\exp(-(x+\mathrm iY)^2)~\mathrm dx =\int_0^1 \exp(-(R(2t-1)+\mathrm iY)^2)\cdot 2R~\mathrm dt}$$

which seems like a very tough integral. I was thinking of a similiar (and more simple) curve $\hat{\gamma}$ using another parametrisation to get easier integrals.

What would be your suggested approach for this problem?

---

**Results of some attempts after getting some help**

After much help of πr8 I have the following results for all four curves thus far

$$
\begin{align*}
 \gamma_1(t) &= (1-t)(-R) + tR = R(2t-1)\\
 \gamma_1'(t) &= 2R\\
 \int_{\gamma_1}\exp(-(x+\mathrm iY)^2)\,\mathrm dx
 &= \int_0^1 \exp(-(\underbrace{R(2t-1)}_{u}+\mathrm iY)^2)\cdot 2R\,\mathrm dt\\
 &= \int_{-R}^R \exp(-(u+\mathrm iY)^2)\,\mathrm du
\end{align*}
$$

---

$$
\begin{align*}
 \gamma_2(t) &= (1-t)R + t(R+\mathrm iY) = R+t\mathrm iY\\
 \gamma_2'(t) &= \mathrm iY\\
 \int_{\gamma_2}\exp(-(x+\mathrm iY)^2)\,\mathrm dx
 &= \int_0^1 \exp(-(\underbrace{R+t\mathrm iY}_{u}+\mathrm iY)^2)\cdot \mathrm iY\,\mathrm dt\\
 &= \int_{R}^{R+\mathrm iY} \exp(-(u+\mathrm iY)^2)\,\mathrm du
\end{align*}
$$

---

$$
\begin{align*}
 \gamma_3(t) &= (1-t)(R+\mathrm iY) + t(-R+\mathrm iY) = R(1-2t)+\mathrm iY\\
 \gamma_3'(t) &= -2R\\
 \int_{\gamma_3}\exp(-(x+\mathrm iY)^2)\,\mathrm dx
 &= \int_0^1 \exp(-(\underbrace{R(1-2t)+\mathrm iY}_{u}+\mathrm iY)^2)\cdot (-2R)\,\mathrm dt\\
 &= \int_{R+\mathrm iY}^{-R+\mathrm iY} \exp(-(u+\mathrm iY)^2)\,\mathrm du
\end{align*}
$$

---

So far I could rewrite all integrals to have the same boundaries as the curves used to deduce them. For the last curve however this wasn't as straight-forward as for the other ones (I was eager to have four identical integrands) and I had to use another substitution yielding

$$
\begin{align*}
 \gamma_4(t) &= (1-t)(-R+\mathrm iY) + t(-R) = -R-(t-1)\mathrm iY\\
 \gamma_4'(t) &= -\mathrm iY\\
 \int_{\gamma_4}\exp(-(x+\mathrm iY)^2)\,\mathrm dx
 &= \int_0^1 \exp(-(\underbrace{-R-t\mathrm iY+\mathrm iY}_{u})^2)\cdot \mathrm iY\,\mathrm dt\\
 &= \int_{-R+\mathrm iY}^{-R} \exp(-u^2)\,\mathrm du.
\end{align*}
$$

---

Is there anything salvageable in the above equations?

Comment: @πr8 I edited the question to add my calculations thus far - please have a look at it as I haven't found too many similiarities besides the boundaries of the integrals and start/end point of the curves.

Comment: You won't get identical integrands: the two horizontal lines should get you the integrals you're looking to compare, and the two vertical lines should tend to $0$ as $R$ increases.

Comment: @πr8 Alright the behaviour of the vertical lines is indeed obvious thus (omitting said vertical lines since their integrals vanish for $R\to\infty$) $$\oint_{\partial Q}\exp(-(x+\mathrm iY)^2)\,\mathrm dx = \int_{-R}^R\exp(-(u+\mathrm iY)^2)\,\mathrm du + \int_{R+\mathrm iY}^{-R+\mathrm iY}\exp(-(u+\mathrm iY)^2)\,\mathrm du.$$ However I am still unsure about deducing something from this in regards to the Gaussian integral.

Comment: 1) Write the second of these as an integral from $-R$ to $R$, 2) the value of the total contour integral is $0$ by the Cauchy integral theorem. Deduce equality

Comment: @πr8 Since the integrand has an antiderivative it follows from the theorem that $$\int_{-R}^R \exp(-(u+\mathrm iY)^2)\,\mathrm du - \int_{-R+\mathrm iY}^{R+\mathrm iY} \exp(-(u+\mathrm iY)^2)\,\mathrm du = 0$$ and thus both integrals are equal. My issue right now is to find the connection to $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp(-x^2)\,\mathrm dx$. Surely it is some simple integration rule, isn't it?

Comment: Your second integral should be from $-R$ to $R$, and the integrand should work out to just be the $\exp(-u^2)$ you need

Comment: @πr8 My last comment was actually false. Letting $u=R(1-2t)+2\mathrm iY$ for the third curve yields $$\int_{R+2\mathrm iY}^{-R+2\mathrm iY}\exp(-u^2)\,\mathrm du$$ while the substitution $u=R(1-2t)$ yields your suggested boundaries with a wrong integrand namely $$\int_{R}^{-R}\exp(-(u+2\mathrm iY)^2)\,\mathrm du.$$ Is it reasonable to take the first substitution I mentioned here show the equality and argue that it doesn't matter that the boundaries are shifted by $2\mathrm iY$ since this is a constant which doesn't matter for $R\to\infty$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $z\mapsto \exp(-z^2)$ is an entire function, by Cauchy's theorem the integral $\int_{\partial Q} \exp(-z^2)\, dz$ is zero. On the other hand,

$$\int_{\partial Q} \exp(-z^2)\, dz = \left(\int_{-R}^R + \int_R^{R + iY} - \int_{-R + iY}^{R + iY} - \int_{-R}^{-R + iY}\right)\exp(-z^2)\, dz$$
Thus

$$\int_{-R + iY}^{R + iY} \exp(-z^2)\, dz = \int_{-R}^R \exp(-x^2)\, dx + \int_R^{R + iY} \exp(-z^2)\, dz - \int_{-R}^{-R + iY} \exp(-z^2)\, dz\tag{1}$$

Now, the integral along the vertical edges of $Q$ are $O\!\left(\exp(-R^2)\right)$ as $R\to \infty$. Indeed, consider the vertical edge from $R$ to $R + iY$, parametrized by $z = R + it, 0 \le t \le Y$.

$$\left\lvert \int_R^{R + iY} \exp(-z^2)\, dz\right\rvert = \left\lvert\int_0^Y \exp\{-(R + it)^2\}i\, dt\right\rvert \le \int_0^Y \exp\{-(R^2 - t^2)\}\, dt = Ce^{-R^2}$$

where $C = \int_0^Y \exp(t^2)\, dt$. Similarly, $\left\lvert\int_{-R}^{-R + iY} \exp(-z^2)\, dz\right\rvert \le Ce^{-R^2}$. Hence, by $(1)$,

$$\int_{-R+iY}^{R + iY} \exp(-z^2)\, dz = \int_{-R}^R \exp(-x^2)\, dx  + O\!\left(\exp(-R^2)\right) \tag{2}
$$

Parametrizing the horizontal edge $[-R + iY,R + iY]$ via $z = x + iY$, $-R\le x \le R$, we have $\int_{-R + iY}^{R + iY} \exp(-z^2)\, dz = \int_{-R}^R \exp(-(x + iY)^2)\, dx$. Therefore, $(2)$ becomes

$$\int_{-R}^R \exp(-(x + iY)^2)\, dx = \int_{-R}^R \exp(-x^2)\, dx + O\!\left(\exp(-R^2)\right)\tag{3}$$ Letting $R \to \infty$ in $(3)$, the result is established.

Comment: So If I understand your approach correctly, you don't start at the integral over $\exp(-(x+\mathrm iY)^2)$ but with the Gaussian integral and then you develop which curves are necessary, isn't it? If I substitute my second curve (from $R$ to $R+\mathrm iY$) in the way to imply it I would get $$\int_{R+\mathrm iY}^{R+2\mathrm iY}\exp(-u^2)\,\mathrm du$$ which is bad since the upper boundary isn't nice.

Comment: And finally, how can you exactly justify the last step in $(2)$ where you replaced $z$ with $x+\mathrm iY$ as well as the boundaries of the integral? I assume one can argue, it is the result of a substitution $z=x+\mathrm iY$ hence reversing it yields the desired result.

Comment: Hi @ChristianIvicevic, I've made some edits so that you can follow the argument clearer.

Comment: Your solution is very thoroughly and not messing around too much with curves as I did - I like your solution. Thank you very much for your input!