# When a kernel is positive?

Tags: heat-equation

I am trying to verify that the heat's kernel is positive using the inverse Fourier transform. For this, I calculate the heat's kernel by means of a contour integral. After verifying this fact, my question arises.

Let \begin{align}
p_t(x):=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \mathrm{e}^{ix\cdot \xi}  \mathrm{e}^{-t|\xi|^2}\,d\xi=:I
\end{align} heat's kernel.

Since
\begin{align}-t|\xi|^2+ix\cdot \xi=-t(\xi_1^2+\cdots+\xi_n^2)+i(x_1\xi_1+\cdots+x_n\xi_n)
\end{align}then

\begin{align}
I=I_1\cdots I_n 
\end{align}

where
$$I_i=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-t\xi_i^2+i x_i\xi_i}\,d\xi_i$$

Now, let
$$I_s:=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-ts^2+i\lambda s}\,ds$$

Let us note that
$$-ts^2+i\lambda s=-(\sqrt{t}s-i\frac{1}{2}\lambda \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}})^2-\frac{1}{4}\lambda^2\frac{1}{t}$$

then
\begin{align}
I_s=\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{1}{4}\lambda^2\frac{1}{t}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{e}^{-(\sqrt{t}s-i\frac{1}{2}\lambda \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}})^2}\,ds
\end{align}

and with $u=\sqrt{t}$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-(u-i\frac{1}{2}\lambda\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}})^2}\,du=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{e}^{-u^2}\,du=\sqrt{\pi}$
([Gaussian integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-(x+\mathrm iY)^2)\,\mathrm d x$ along $[-R,R]+\mathrm i[0,Y]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1766787/gaussian-integral-int-infty-infty-exp-x-mathrm-iy2-mathrm-d-x-a))

\begin{align}
I_s=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{t}}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{1}{4}\lambda^2\frac{1}{t}}
\end{align}

Therefore, $I=(I_s)^n>0$

If $f(\xi)=|\xi|^2$, we see that $f(\xi)$ is positive (and elliptic).

**Question 1.** In general, if $f(\xi)$ is positive and elliptic, then is the kernel $p_t(x):=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\mathrm{e}^{ix\cdot\xi}\mathrm{e}^{-tf(\xi)}\,d\xi$ is positive?
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by elliptic? The level curves of $f$ are ellipsoids?

Comment: For positivity arguments, see [here.](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/bulletin-of-the-australian-mathematical-society/article/on-positivity-of-fourier-transforms/D232B9DEB4819E4D2FF17E8162B8B066#)

Comment: @Cameron $f$ elliptic if $(1+|\xi|)^m\leq |f(\xi)|$ for all $|\xi|>R$ some $R>0$.